# Is there any benefit to creating a nonclustered index on 2 fields that are already present in the clustered index?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I have a table with 3 fields in the clustered index (they are the PKs of the table). One of those fields is no longer useful, so I'm wondering if querying is being slowed down by indexing on a field that's no longer important.

To try to solve this, I am considering creating a nonclustered index on `Field1` and `Field2`. Most of the time for queries on this table, we will only query on `Field1`, but I figured I'd also add `Field2` in there (if I should only make the index on `Field1` feel free to tell me).

Is there any benefit to creating a nonclustered index on 2 fields that are already present in the clustered index?

```
TableA
--clustered index on: Field1 varchar(20), UselessField2 varchar(13), Field3 varchar(20)
--new nonclustered index on: Field1 varchar(20), Field3 varchar(20)
```

Comment: A primary key is more than just a clustered index (and in fact does not have to be clustered), it *defines* what is considered a unique row. So you can't just remove that column unless you are sure it won't break the relational principles in your database design. What is the actual purpose of that column? Some real names might be useful.

Comment: @Charlieface It was going to be a way to link fields between tables, but we aren't implementing this same field in other tables so it only exists in this one. Therefore, it is Useless(TM)

Comment: Also, even if I was to remove UselessField2, uniqueness would not be impacted. This field was erroneously made into a PK.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, there are two main benefits.**

- Any queries using that index need to read less data, as each page contains less columns.
- More importantly, queries which filter by `Field1` and `Field3`, and *not* by `UselessField2` can seek direct to the rows they need, without reading anything extra. This cannot be done with the current index.

The second point could in theory have been mitigated by re-ordering the primary key.

---

**Having said that, you have two even better options:**

- Change the primary key to non-clustered (possibly re-ordering it as well), and make the new index clustered. The primary key does *not* have to be clustered, although it normally is due to querying concerns.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
DROP CONSTRAINT YourPK;

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX new_clustered_index ON YourTable
  (Field1, Field3);

ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT YourPK PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
  (Field1, Field3, UselessField2);
```

- Given what you have said in the comments, the whole column can be deleted, or at the very least removed from the PK, without affecting its uniqueness.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
DROP CONSTRAINT YourPK;

ALTER TABLE YourTable
DROP COLUMN UselessField2;

ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD CONSTRAINT YourPK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  (Field1, Field3);
```